# .Net Core upgrade to 3.1 throwing error for GetType().ShortDisplayName

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I have upgraded my projects from .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.1. Currently everything is working fine except below error -

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS1061 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'ShortDisplayName' and
> no accessible extension method 'ShortDisplayName' accepting a first
> argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

Code is as below :

```
ex.GetType().ShortDisplayName()
```

I believe there should be some substitute available for **ShortDisplayName** in 3.1 but don't know how to get it.

Kindly help.

Comment: There has never been a `ShortDisplayName` member on `System.Type`. [A search on Microsoft shows where it is referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/search/?scope=.NET&terms=ShortDisplayName&category=Reference). You likely had an extension method or something defined.

Comment: `ShortDisplayName` doesn't exist in [.NET Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: There's an extension method in [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.typeextensions.shortdisplayname?view=efcore-6.0) though, is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

First add package to your project. It's package name described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.typeextensions.shortdisplayname?view=efcore-3.1)

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -v 3.1.0
```

Then, You should add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` as using statement.

Answer (score -1):

`Type` class has never had a method with this name and if it had, its name would start with `Get` and be `GetShortDisplayName()`.

The lack of `Get` strongly suggests that this is a custom extension method that you didn't yet port to your new project.